# getId() on a LiveChatMessage returning null -- YT Data API v3

Tags: java, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get the ID of a [LiveChatMessage](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages#resource) with the method `getId()`. It for some reason returns `null`. Can somebody help me?

Here is part of my code now.

```
LiveChatMessageListResponse response = youtube
                            .liveChatMessages()
                            .list(liveChatId, "snippet, authorDetails")
                            .setPageToken(nextPageToken)
                            .setFields(LIVE_CHAT_FIELDS)
                            .execute();

List<LiveChatMessage> messages = response.getItems();
for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
    LiveChatMessage message = messages.get(i);
    final String[] full = new String[2];
    System.out.println("ID: " + message.getId());
```

Here are my `LIVE_CHAT_FIELDS`.

```
private static final String LIVE_CHAT_FIELDS =
    "items(authorDetails(channelId,displayName,isChatModerator,isChatOwner,isChatSponsor,"
        + "profileImageUrl),snippet(displayMessage,superChatDetails,publishedAt)),"
        + "nextPageToken,pollingIntervalMillis";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `LIVE_CHAT_FIELDS` do not include the ID.

Include the ID in `items(`:

```
private static final String LIVE_CHAT_FIELDS =
    "items(id,authorDetails(channelId,displayName,isChatModerator,isChatOwner,isChatSponsor,"
        + "profileImageUrl),snippet(displayMessage,superChatDetails,publishedAt)),"
        + "nextPageToken,pollingIntervalMillis";
```